# Get the previous item from a list through the index of the later

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to get the index of a list and substract 1 to get te previous value.

```
thursday = LastThursdayOfTheMonth(j, i);

if(LStock.Any(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2))) 
{
       object line = LStock.First(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2));
        LFridays.Add(line);
}
```

I want to add the previous element on the list. How can i do that?

Thanks!

**Solved**

```
if(LStock.Any(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2))) 
{
      line = LStock.First(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2));
      int index = LStock.IndexOf(line) - 1;
      LFridays.Add(LStock.ElementAt(index));
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this (for example by creating an extension method that drags a sliding window of 2 elements over your), but a list might be the most straightforward.

Comment: Your solution is terrible. It's doing up to 4 linear searches of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided compilable code, so I can't verify this without making a bunch of additions and probably assumptions, but this should work.

```
var line = LStock.FirstOrDefault(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2));
if (line != null)
{
  int index = LStock.IndexOf(line) - 1;
  LFridays.Add(LStock.ToList().ElementAt(index));
}
```

If `LStock` is already a `List`, `.ToList()` can be omitted.

Comment: mi code works but the list obtains the exact values not the previous

Comment: this doesn't make sense. Why are you assigning in an if statement and why are you using type `object`. I know you don't know what it is from the question so use `var` instead

Comment: @Dalio141, even though your code works, you haven't provided enough of it for others to compile it. My example finds the index of your element and subtracts one, uses that to find the previous element.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, what I did is possible, but I agree that it's more readable the other way, plus we won't have to use the object type (even though that's what's used in the question). I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var find = thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2);

var current =
    LStock
        .Skip(1)
        .Zip(LStock, (n, c) => new { next = n.date, current = c.date })
        .First(x => x.next == find)
        .current;
```